# How to swap % in NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()

Tags: android

I am using `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()` for formating integer to get **100 %**.

Code i used is

```
    NumberFormat mProgressPercentFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    mProgressPercentFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    String text = mProgressPercentFormat.format(100);
```

Result:
        **100 %**

Expected Result:
        **% 100**

Can any one tell me how to Format in NumberFormat itself or any other alternative solution.

```
My main goal to switch % infront of number based on Locale change.
```

eg: 
English : 100 %

Arabic  : % 100

Comment: Are you sure that whenever you will execute your program in English language then you will get % at last position??

Comment: Passing `Locale` inside `getPercentInstance()` may fix your problem. Like `NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.US);` // Try to pass SA-Saudi Arabia or some gulf countries code.

Comment: My actuall requirement is in android.app.ProgressDialog class has a method called "setProgressPercentFormat(NumberFormat format)". So i need to provide NumberFormat format which will result %100 for arabic and 100% for english. I know by default Locale support is done by getPercentInstance(). Number are convered to arabic numberic. but % has to come front. It is requirement for arabic number